# "Thread-19" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-19

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to embed Swing JEditorPane into JavaFX project as below code.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    SyntaxTester ob = new SyntaxTester(filepath);
    SwingNode swingnode = new SwingNode();
    editor = ob.getEditor();
    editor.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getKeyChar() == 's') {
                if (evt.isControlDown()) {
                    WebController.setSaveSymbol();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(editor, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    swingnode.setContent(scrollpane);
    tab.setContent(swingnode);
    tab.setText(new File(filepath).getName());
    tab.setId(filepath);
    tab.getTooltip().setText(filepath);
});
```

I am trying to update name of the Tab on keylistener of JEditorPane, it throw exception

> "Thread-19" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-19

I do understand, i am calling JavaFX main thread from Swing thread that is producing this exception. So what could be the solution? Is there any other JavaFx controller i can use to fire key event? Thanks in advance.

exception stack

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TabPaneSkin$TabHeaderSkin.handlePropertyChanged(TabPaneSkin.java:1360)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TabPaneSkin$TabHeaderSkin.lambda$new$489(TabPaneSkin.java:1122)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
at javafx.scene.control.Tab.setText(Tab.java:281)
at com.agnisys.idsnextgen.classes.WebController.setUnsaveSymbol(WebController.java:143)
at com.agnisys.idsnextgen.richeditor.ActivateEditor$1$1.keyPressed(ActivateEditor.java:143)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6497)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6316)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1103)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:974)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:800)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (including the stacktrace as @Slaw already suggested)

Comment: @Slaw yes i have add full exception stack

Comment: It doesn't seem like you should do all of your swing work on the platform thread. Your action listener will happen on the EDT even through you are creating everything on the platform thread, so you have to do all of your javafx on the platform thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) to invoke it on the javafx thread.

```
Platform.runLater(()->{
    WebController.setSaveSymbol();
});
```

Comment: Anywhere you modify a javafx object, then you need to do it on the application thread. Where else does it happen?